# Is it possible to kill the parent thread from within a child thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, time

I am using Python 3.5.2 on windows.

I would like to run a python script but guarantee that it will not take more than **N** seconds. If it *does* take more than **N** seconds, an exception should be raised, and the program should exit. Initially I had thought I could just launch a thread at the beginning that waits for **N** seconds before throwing an exception, but this only manages to throw an exception to the timer thread, not to the parent thread. For example:

```
import threading
import time

def may_take_a_long_time(name, wait_time):
    print("{} started...".format(name))
    time.sleep(wait_time)
    print("{} finished!.".format(name))

def kill():
    time.sleep(3)
    raise TimeoutError("No more time!")

kill_thread = threading.Thread(target=kill)
kill_thread.start()

may_take_a_long_time("A", 2)
may_take_a_long_time("B", 2)
may_take_a_long_time("C", 2)
may_take_a_long_time("D", 2)
```

This outputs:

```
A started...
A finished!.
B started...
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "timeout.py", line 11, in kill
    raise TimeoutError("No more time!")
    TimeoutError: No more time!

B finished!.
C started...
C finished!.
D started...
D finished!.
```

Is this even remotely possible? I realize I could do something like this:

```
import threading
import time

def may_take_a_long_time(name, wait_time, thread):
    if not thread.is_alive():
        return
    print("{} started...".format(name))
    time.sleep(wait_time)
    print("{} finished!.".format(name))

def kill():
    time.sleep(3)
    raise TimeoutError("No more time!")

kill_thread = threading.Thread(target=kill)
kill_thread.start()

may_take_a_long_time("A", 2, kill_thread)
may_take_a_long_time("B", 2, kill_thread)
may_take_a_long_time("C", 2, kill_thread)
may_take_a_long_time("D", 2, kill_thread)
```

But this method fails if, for example, `may_take_a_long_time("B", 60, kill_thread)` was called.

So I guess my TL;DR question is, what's the best way to put a time limit on the main thread itself?

Comment: You can't _kill_ Python threads at all. There's just no API for that. And what you're doing in your code is just raising an exception within _a new thread_, that doesn't affect the main one.

Comment: What is the purpose of the time limit? If you don't want to wait for something to happen for more than a certain amount of time, you just stop waiting.

Comment: @ForceBru I know that it doesn't affect the main one, that's my problem. This was my initial naive implementation. I'm trying to find out how to ensure that the series of functions (`may_take_a_long_time`) don't take more than **N** seconds.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`_thread.interrupt_main`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) (this module is called `thread` in Python 2.7):

```
import time, threading, _thread

def long_running():
    while True:
        print('Hello')

def stopper(sec):
    time.sleep(sec)
    print('Exiting...')
    _thread.interrupt_main()

threading.Thread(target = stopper, args = (2, )).start()

long_running()
```

Comment: Hey thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for (and fast too!). Do you know if it's possible to change what exception is thrown? `KeyboardInterrupt` doesn't seem very relevant to what I'm doing.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, the docs says it: this function only throws `KeyboardInterrupt`s. You could, actually, involve some trickery with a global variable indicating that the exception was raised by `stopper` and process this case differently. But if you catch the exception in the main thread, the long running function will be terminated, and its results lost, so you may want to handle it _inside that function itself_.

Comment: I used @ForceBru's suggestion in the child thread and handled the `KeyboardInterrupt` by calling `os._exit(0)` as suggested by @rbanffy below.

Answer (score 6):

If the parent thread is the root thread, you may want to try `os._exit(0)`.

```
import os
import threading
import time

def may_take_a_long_time(name, wait_time):
    print("{} started...".format(name))
    time.sleep(wait_time)
    print("{} finished!.".format(name))

def kill():
    time.sleep(3)
    os._exit(0)

kill_thread = threading.Thread(target=kill)
kill_thread.start()

may_take_a_long_time("A", 2)
may_take_a_long_time("B", 2)
may_take_a_long_time("C", 2)
may_take_a_long_time("D", 2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I'm guessing that `sys.exit()` is limited to whatever thread is what called from, without having any way to change the parent's behavior.

Comment: That works a lot better, but I'm probably unlikely to use it, since it doesn't actually cause an exception or throw an error.

Comment: You can return something else to the calling process to signal the timeout. Usually, returning 0 means everything went OK. I am not sure what you can return on Windows (last time I checked, in DOS you were able to return an int, but that was a long time ago).

Answer (score -1):

The cleanest way to do this is to have a queue that the parent thread checks on a regular basis. If the child wants to kill the parent, it sends a message (e.g. "DIE") to the queue. The parent checks the queue and if it sees the message it dies.

```
    q = queue.Queue()
    bc = queue.Queue()          # backchannel

    def worker():
    while True:
            key = q.get()
            try:
                process_key(key)
            except ValueError as e:
                bc.put('DIE')
            q.task_done()

    # Start the threads
    for i in range(args.threads):
        threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()

    for obj in object_farm():
        q.put(obj)
        try:
            back = bc.get(block=False)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            print("Data received on backchannel:",back)
            if back=='DIE':
                raise RuntimeError("time to die")
```